# How to prevent _User table from growing unnecessarily when using PFAnonymousUtils iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

What is the best way to handle the scenario described below? 
I am giving the user limited access (READONLY) when logged in anonymously. 
The problem i am facing is that i am afraid is that the _User table would grow unnecessarily with redundant data.

Steps:
1. user logged in anonymously
2. clear cache
3. logged in anonymously again
problem : rows in _User table is added, older user is not removed.

Code:

```
    + (void) ParseLoginAnonymouslyWithBlock:(LoginAnonymousBLock)completionBlock {

//    if ([PFUser currentUser] && [ParseUtilities isUserAnonymous]) {
//        // user already logged in anonymously.
//        // prevent duplicates in table
//        completionBlock([PFUser currentUser], nil);
//        return;
//    }


    [PFAnonymousUtils logInWithBlock:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
//        if (error) {
//            completionBlock (user, error);
//        } else {
//            completionBlock (user, error);
//        }
        completionBlock(user, error);
    }];
}
```

In View controller:

```
- (IBAction)loginGuestTapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Guest Login tapped");

    [ParseUtilities ParseLoginAnonymouslyWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", &error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"success");
            // user logged in
            NSLog(@"isanonymous: %i and %@", [ParseUtilities isUserAnonymous], [PFUser currentUser]);


        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Why do you actually need to log the user in for read only access?

Comment: The read only access is only for certain tables , which would require more information which is missing in the anonymous user info. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add a 'latest_activity' flag into every user and update it when the user uses your app.

Then create a BackgroundJob (https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud_code) and remove the anonymous users that are older than ~2weeks?

What you could also do is setup Push Notifications in you app and for each user that gave you a push notification token make sure the push notification does not 'reach' the recipient. In that case you can delete him since he doesn't even have the app installed anymore. (False positives are much lower in this case than the other, but you should combine them anyway!)